# Copies and bindings between python objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, reference

Given a matrix, A of size M x N of 0s and 1s. If an element is 0, set its entire row and column to 0.

```
Input 1:
    [   [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1]   ]

Output 1:
    [   [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]   ]
```

My Code:

```
def setZeroes(self, A):
    B=A
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            if(A[i][j]==0):
                for x in range(len(A[i])):
                    B[i][x]=0
                    for y in range(len(A)):
                        B[y][j]=0
        A=B
    return A
```

Is creating a zero matrix. What do I miss ?

Comment: an array is a reference type, `return A` is not required, and also `B=A`, `A=B`

Comment: why `self`? why `B=A` and `A=B`?

Comment: @hadi 'reference type' has not much meaning in python - all variables work the same way (the difference is whether they point to a mutable object or not)... `A` is a reference to (or better: a *name* of)  a mutable object.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist you're right, thank you

Comment: Yup, that and its part of a class called solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import copy

def setZeroes(A):
   B=copy.deepcopy(A)
   for i in range(len(A)):
       for j in range(len(A[i])):
           if(A[i][j]==0):
               for x in range(len(A[i])):
                   B[i][x]=0
               for y in range(len(A)):
                   B[y][j]=0
   return B

A =  [   [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1]   ]

print(setZeroes(A))
```

since, array is pass  by reference, you have  to deepcopy it.

Comment: Thanks, I have other methods of solving this which are more efficient, I wanted to know where I was going wrong with my  particular solution. (Everybody else provided their own implementations for the problem)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by masking rows and columns with a zero

```
mask = A==0
A[:, mask.any(0)] = 0
A[mask.any(1)] = 0
print(A)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def func(l):    
    r = []
    c = []
    
    # storing the index value of column and row where there is 0 everywhere
    for i,v1 in enumerate(l):
        for j,v2 in enumerate(v1):
            if v2 ==0:
                c.append(j)
                r.append(i)
    r = list(set(r))
    c = list(set(c))
    
    # making all element of row 0
    for i in r:
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            l[i][j] = 0
            
    # making lal element of column 0
    for i in c:
        for j in range(len(l)):
            l[j][i] = 0
    return l


l = [   [1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1], 
        [1, 1, 1]   ]

res = func(l)

print(res,sep='\n')
```

output:

```
[
 [0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 1]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is right here:

```
B=A
```

This doesn't create three new arrays for the rows of B: it makes B point to the same arrays as A. So as soon as you set the first row and column to zeros, there are additional zeroes which your loop discovers. Copy each row (or deep copy) to avoid the problem.

Comment: I knew that they'll refer to the same object , but thought if I changed one of the referenced, it would create another object for that.

Comment: "copy on write"? No, it can't guess whether you want data to remain shared or to duplicate it. It remains shared. Deepcopy duplicates everything, instead of copying the reference. Easiest with the `copy.deepcopy()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple answer which does not modify A but create another matrix which is returned:

```
from more_itertools import locate


def setZeroes(A):
    indexPosList = []   #  will contains all the zeroable indices
    result = []  # the result matrix
    for i in A:
        indexPosList.extend(list(locate(i, lambda a: a == 0)))
        if 0 in i:
            result.append([0]*len(i))
        else:
            for idx in indexPosList:
                i[idx] = 0
            result.append(i)
    return result
```

Sample test:

```
>>> A = [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> setZeroes(A)
[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a full python implementation that correctly changes A in place including changing columns

```
def set_zero(A):
    columns = set()
    for row_nr, row in enumerate(A):
        if 0 in row:
            columns |= {i for i, c in enumerate(row) if c == 0}
            A[row_nr] = [0] * len(row)
    for row_nr,  row in enumerate(A):
        A[row_nr] = [0 if i in columns else c for i, c in enumerate(row)]
```